# Python String Formatting ":<10" meaning?

Tags: python

I was following some documentation and just couldn´t remember what :<10 did in string formatting.

```
print(f"{var:<10}")
```

And if you know a good site were I can read up on it again please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

From https://realpython.com/python-formatted-output/

> A value using the less than sign (<) indicates that the output is left-justified

Let's say `var = "foo"`. Your code snippet will print `'foo       '` - a string of length 10 with the contents of `var` left-justified.

```
print(f"{var:<10}")
         ^~~ ^~~
#  variable : string format modifier
```